# What does the finished parameter in the completion block mean in animateWithDuration

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

I'm trying to understand how view animations work in iOS; i currently have an animation that i create with:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                      delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
                 animations:(void (^)(void))animations
                 completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

But I've got a question concerning the finished parameter in the completion block; what the finished parameter does i somewhat understand in the sense that if finished is YES the animation actually happened which is a good thing, **but what does it mean when it is set to NO and what is the common way to deal with this normally**, especially if you want to chain animations (calling a next animation in the completion block) that work on the same view?

The reason I ask is because it returns NO at sometimes for reasons unclear to me, as the view is present in the view hierarchy and there are no other animations intervening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that for some reason or another the animation did not complete. The view could have been removed from its superview for example or another animation could have been applied to it, or a number of other reasons best known to Apple. How you deal with it is up to you. You could start the entire animation chain again, start at the last animation, or the next.

Comment: well, of course is it up to me, but it would be nice to know what the actual cause of not finishing is such that I can act accordingly. It does the job most of the time, but there are some situations in which I do get NO returned while I ruled out: the view not being visible, the view having other animations, the view or any of its subviews not having correct size.

Comment: @MrJre Apple's doc give very little info as far as I can see about the causes of animations not finishing so it seems hard to react in any other way than generically. Let us know if you work out why they are failing in your case.